# What happens to an int if it's not initilized?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I found this question, and whenever I try to run it, it gives me an error that it could not compile  because the variable r has not been initialized. This is the question....

```
int n=1; int k=2; int r;
if(k<r) {
  r=n;
}
```

"What is the value of each variable after the if statement?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already answered the question. The code doesn't compile. Unlike when used as a class member local primitive types do not have a default value. And since it doesn't compile it can't execute.

Answer (score 3):

Since the code can't pass compilation, the if statement is never executed. Nothing is executed, so none of the variables have values.

Answer (score 0):

When an int is not initialized or generally when a variable is not initialized (other than static methods/fields in classes) it cannot be used.
You can have a variable like int x; and compile a program where x is not initialized BUT not used as well, in this case it will work